# Is There A WordPress Plugin That Produces PDFs of Posts Locally?

Tags: posts, pdf

Most of the WordPress PDF plugins out there use services like Joliprint and Print Friendly to convert posts to PDFs.

Is there a plugin that does this locally utilizing the power of PHP (and/or WordPress), I mean, without using an external service?

Comment: **Note To Self:** This is a resource hog; and a not-so-necessary feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was half way through writing a long answer explaining why there weren't any ... when I found one.

[WP Post to PDF](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-post-to-pdf/) is a plugin, updated for WP 3.3.2, that generates PDFs locally and caches them for later.